# Can my university network IT see that I am using Tor when I am using Tor Browser with an obfs4 pluggable transport?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, pluggable-transports, obfs4, login

I use my private laptop computer and Tor Browser with an obfs4 pluggable transport to log in my university account.

The university network IT does not use Deep Packet Inspection, and the university network IT does not require me to install special software to log in my account.

If the university network IT is unable to see that I am using Tor, why is the university network IT unable to see I am using Tor?

Answer (score 1):

The Tor Project put out a basic [obfs4 Transport Evaluation](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/PluggableTransports/Obfs4Evaluation). The pertinent quote is:

> The (obfs4) design improves on the vulnerability to censorship based
>   on active attackers identifying suspect flows and attempting to
>   confirm which protocol is running via active attacks

The page goes on to say that it would be very difficult and expensive to try to prove that you are using Tor using standard techniques.

If you live in China, there are other options such as [meek](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/meek) which will disguise traffic as if it is connecting to an unblocked service.

See Also: https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en